# Basic question in assigning value to unordered_map

Tags: c++

I have an unordered_map which stores the int as key an pointer as value. I need to check the existence of the key. If the key is not available, I need to insert the key and value. Which one is the better approach?

Thanks.

```
unordered_map<int, classA*>testMap;
classA* ptr = testMap[1];
if(ptr == NULL)
   testMap[1] = new classA;


OR

unordered_map<int, classA*>::iterator it = testMap.find(1);
if(it == testMap.end())
{
  testMap.insert(make_pair(1, new classA));
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you store your dynamically created `classA` instances in a `std::shared_ptr`: `std::unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr<classA>>`. You can create the instances using `std::make_shared<classA>(...ctr params...)`. This relieves you of the worries of resource leaks.

Comment: The first approach or a the variant that avoids the second lookup might be better if you can say for sure that never have valid null pointers in the map. However, as you have not stated that precondition I would go for the second, safe approach. You could use the count() function instead of find and/or get rid of the it local variable to make the code cleared.

Answer (score 6):

Neither method is good because both use *two* queries into the map where one would be sufficient.

A better method is retrieving a reference to the element, and if that reference is a null pointer, assign to it:

```
classA*& ptr = testMap[1];
if (ptr == 0)
    ptr = new classA;
```

This works because querying a non-existing element in a map automatically inserts it (default-constructed, thus a null pointer will be inserted), and `operator[]` returns a *reference* to that element (be it newly created or already existing).

But notice that the semantics between this method (or your first method) and your second method subtly differ: your second method only inserts the element if the key doesn’t exist in the map. My method (and your first method) also create a new element if the key in fact already existed, but its value was a null pointer.

Comment: What if that key already exists and `NULL` is a valid value for it?

Comment: This isn't a good idea in general though. If you were storing something other than pointers then you might not have a suitable default value to test against. Also, efficiency is really a non-issue here as the memory allocation will take much longer than the lookup.

Comment: @Peter: That’s true. But it **is** the best method in this case. As for efficiency being a non-issue, I beg to differ. You’re right that the memory allocation will likely outweigh the lookup. But that’s no carte blanche to needlessly perform redundant operations.

Comment: It's not needless, it makes maintenance easier if e.g. NULL becomes a valid value, or if the type of the value changes.

Answer (score 1):

The second is the better approach. In the first, when you do `classA* ptr = testMap[1]`, you are creating an item in the hash with the default value of `NULL`.

If you were to change the map value to something other than a pointer (maybe a `vector` for example) then you might not have a suitable default value to test against. Also, in the future, `NULL` might be a valid value for your map, so your default value test would be meaningless.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would say the second approach with another reason: you are never creating entries which are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
typedef unordered_map<int, classA*>::iterator my_iterator;
std::pair<my_iterator, my_iterator> range = testMap.equal_range(1);
if (range.first == range.second) //element not in map
{
    testMap.insert(range.first, new classA);
}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to lijie for pointing out that this is pointless. `equal_range` returns and `[end, end]` pair if the value is not found for `underoded_map`.

Comment: If the element is not in the `unordered_map` both iterators returned by `equal_range` are `end()`. So I doubt the `insert` hint is useful. (i.e. it is equivalent to `testMap.insert(testMap.end(), new classA)`. which is an error in any case; it should be a pair).

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was thinking about a standard ordered map, sorry. I'm not sure what you mean by an error, underoder_map has an insert-function which takes two arguments, one iterator and one value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982322.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In terms of efficiency I believe they are equivalent.

In the first case, if the entry doesn't already exist then the call to:

```
classA* ptr = testMap[1];
```

will actually create an empty element in the map which you would then populate during the if statement.

The second will only add an entry to the map when you call `insert`.

So I suppose it comes down to which style suits you better!